# OpenCV Python calcOpticalFlowFarneback

Tags: python, opencv

Thanks a lot, if any people can help me. Im try, use a example of book "OReilly Programming Computer Vision with Python", at end of page 216.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
def draw_flow(im,flow,step=16):
    h,w = im.shape[:2]
    y,x = mgrid[step/2:h:step,step/2:w:step].reshape(2,-1)
    fx,fy = flow[y,x].T

    # create line endpoints
    lines = vstack([x,y,x+fx,y+fy]).T.reshape(-1,2,2)
    lines = int32(lines)

    # create image and draw
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in lines:
        cv2.line(vis,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),1)
        cv2.circle(vis,(x1,y1),1,(0,255,0), -1)
    return vis


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret,im = cap.read()
prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

while True:
    # get grayscale image
    ret,im = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # compute flow
    #flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray,gray,None,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0)
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray,gray,float(0),float(0),3,15,3,5,float(1),0)
    prev_gray = gray

    # plot the flow vectors
    cv2.imshow('Optical flow',draw_flow(gray,flow))
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
```

Im execute in terminal (LXUbuntu, lxterminal) and i get the follow error:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw.py", line 35, in <module>
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray,gray,None,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0)
TypeError: a float is required
```

I understand that the problem is in the function calcOpticalFlowFarneback, because this need a number in float, hence, im try calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray,gray,None,float(0.5),3,15,3,5,float(1.2),0) but dont work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "a float is required" would probably be referring to non-float, non-int arguments in the argument list ..

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the code a little bit.

First of all, include Numpy library since methods like `mgrid`, `int32`, `vstack` are numpy functions.

So at top of the code, add :

```
from numpy import *
```

Second, coming to your question, fourth argument should be an `int`. You have supplied it as float. Make it 1 (or 3, as you like). And last argument is output itself. You don't need it. So remove it.

So my final statement look like below (and it works fine for me) :

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray,gray,0.5,1,3,15,3,5,1)
```

Try this, and let me know if any error comes.

Answer (score 5):

@sunside

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0) 

cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev, next, flow, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags) → flow
```

is opencv3.x  grama,see alose [opencv3.x doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)

Otherwise:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0) 
TypeError: a float is required

cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev, next, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags[, flow])
```

you must had run at opencv2.x, it can be asserted like this:

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

See [opencv2.x doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Python3, insert in `def draw_flow`

```
y, x = np.mgrid[step/2:h:step, step/2:w:step].reshape(2,-1).astype(int) 
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

For Python 2 you should use

```
y, x = np.mgrid[step/2:h:step, step/2:w:step].reshape(2,-1)
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

When  I invoke the function as follows, the following error message is displayed:

```
 flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

Error:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0) 
TypeError: a float is required
```

When I delete the value `None` then my program works correctly:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

Function `calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` takes shape:

```
cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev, next, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags[, flow]) → flow
```

It turns out that we should not pass the value of `None` for parameter `pyr_scale`. We can pass `None` to parameter `flow` though.

- `pyr_scale`: a parameter, specifying the image scale (<1) to build pyramids for each image; `pyr_scale = 0.5` means a classical pyramid, where each next layer is twice smaller than the previous one.
- `flow`: computed flow image that has the same size as `prvs` and type `CV_32FC2`.

Comment: As they noted, this is unrelated comment, however here is why this is happening:
Because the function accepts different parameters in python 2 and python 3. So, make sure you are reading the manual matching your environment. You can check that with cv2.cv.__version__